# Creating FeatureCollection with values stored in an Array on Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, list, array, feature-collection

I applied an unsupervised classification to a collection of Sentinel 2 images and used ReducetoVector() within a loop to obtain each class of the Unsupervised classification as a different object.

Afterwards, I was able calculate the mean of Reflectance inside each different class obtained using ReduceRegion() wihin another loop, and I have those values stored into an array.

I want to export those values to my Drive as a CSV file but to do that using 'Export.table.toDrive' it seems that I need to create FeatureCollection with the values stored in the array, and that's what I'm not being able to do. Here's a bit of the code:

```
var mediana = colecao.median();
var regiao = ee.Geometry.Polygon(lagoa);

//treinamento
var treinamento = mediana.sample({
  region: lagoa,
  scale: 10,
  numPixels: 5000,
});

//define o tipo de cluster que será usado e parametros de treinamento
var agrupamento = ee.Clusterer.wekaXMeans(15,20).train(treinamento);

//diz qual cluster usar na imagem
var resultado = mediana.clip(lagoa).cluster(agrupamento);

//separando cada classe de cluster
var poly = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i += 1){
//define o contador
var contador = ee.Number(i);
var subset = resultado.select("cluster").eq(i).selfMask();
poly[i] = subset.reduceToVectors(null, lagoa, 10);
//Map.addLayer(subset.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'only_'+i.toString());
}

var media_p = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i += 1){
media_p[i] = mediana.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), poly[i], 10, null, null, false, 1e13);
print('media_p'+i.toString(), media_p[i]);
}

Export.table.toDrive({
collection: TBD,
description:'media_clusters',
folder: 'GEE',
fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

I've tried quite a few things and none of the worked.

Can somebody guide me on how to proceed?

Here is a link to the full code if needed: https://code.earthengine.google.com/72926cb481767d1b58ed7e31cf52c611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
var media_clusters = ee.FeatureCollection(media_p
  .map(function (dict, i) {
    return ee.Feature(null, dict) 
    // return ee.Feature(poly[i].geometry(), dict) // If you want to include the geometries
  })
)
```